# SQL: Inserción de datos en VARRAY que contiene un objeto de usuario

Tags: sql, poo, oracle-sqldeveloper

Imaginemos que tenemos la siguiente declaración de este tipo de objeto:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  Persona AS OBJECT (
codigo INTEGER,
DNI VARCHAR2(10),
Nombre VARCHAR2(30),
Apellidos VARCHAR2(30),
fecha_nac DATE);
```

Y ahora la declaración de un varray del tipo creado anteriormente:

`CREATE TYPE ListaPersonas AS VARRAY(10) OF Persona`

**Cual sería el procedimiento para introducir dos instancias de `Persona` en `ListaPersonas` partiendo de que ya están creadas?**

```
DECLARE
persona1 Persona;
persona2 Persona;
BEGIN
persona1 := NEW Persona(1,'DNIFICTICIO','Juan','Romero',03/16/1992);
persona2 := NEW Persona(1,'DNIFICTICIO2','Ana','Ramirez',02/11/1995);

--Inserción de las personas en el VARRAY

END;
```